# Disabling submit button if the file upload is not completed in dropzone js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I having two forms, where I am uploading two diffrent files.I am using  single submit button to process both the files. Here,I want to disable the submit button when no file is uploaded or only one file is uploaded

Here is my code

```
  <html>
        <script>
       Dropzone.options.myDropzone  = {  
                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                autoProcessQueue: true,
                maxFiles: 1,
                queueLimit:1,
                accept: function(file, done) {
                  console.log("uploaded");
                  done();
                },
               };
       Dropzone.options.myDropzone1  = {  
                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                autoProcessQueue: true,
                maxFiles: 1,
                queueLimit:1,
                accept: function(file, done) {
                  console.log("uploaded");
                  done();
                },
               };
    </script>
    <body>
    <form action="{% url 'myapp:upload_dropzone1' %}" id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone" method="post" required enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                  <div class="fallback">
                                    <input name="file" type="file" />
                                  </div>
                              </form>

    <form action="{% url 'myapp:upload_dropzone2' %}" id="my-dropzone1" class="dropzone" method="post" required enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                              <div class="fallback">
                                <input name="file" type="file" />
                              </div>
                          </form>
                             <button  type="submit" id="validate" >Submit</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Disable it on submit and enable it in the accept function

Comment: I want to enable the submit button, if both the file is uploaded only

Comment: You can listen for the inputs' `change` events.

Comment: So count. Have a counter that is zero and in the accept function add one see if it is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
        <script>
       var RemainingUploads = 2;
       function checkEndUploads(){
           if(!RemainingUploads)
               document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false;
           }
       }
       Dropzone.options.myDropzone  = {  
                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                autoProcessQueue: true,
                maxFiles: 1,
                queueLimit:1,
                accept: function(file, done) {
                  console.log("uploaded");
                  done();
                },
                success: function(){
                    RemainingUploads --;
                    checkEndUploads();
                }
               };
       Dropzone.options.myDropzone1  = {  
                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                autoProcessQueue: true,
                maxFiles: 1,
                queueLimit:1,
                accept: function(file, done) {
                  console.log("uploaded");
                  done();
                },
                success: function(){
                    RemainingUploads --;
                    checkEndUploads();
                }
               };
    </script>
    <body>
    <form action="{% url 'myapp:upload_dropzone1' %}" id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone" method="post" required enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                  <div class="fallback">
                                    <input name="file" type="file" />
                                  </div>
                              </form>

    <form action="{% url 'myapp:upload_dropzone2' %}" id="my-dropzone1" class="dropzone" method="post" required enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                              <div class="fallback">
                                <input name="file" type="file" />
                              </div>
                          </form>
                             <button id="submitButton" type="submit" id="validate" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should use`if(!RemainingUploads`)

Comment: Yes  morteza.I have initialised an another variable in  `removedfile: function(file)` used that in `checkEndUploads`to disable the button,if the file is removed

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
uploadMultiple: true
```

instead of use two separate upload.

[config-uploadMultiple](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-uploadMultiple)

[event-processingmultiple](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-processingmultiple)